# Is it possible to modify a control property's get and set methods without extending the control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, web-controls, hidden-field

Suppose I'm running a site with many .aspx pages that inherit from a file called `FormPage.cs`.  When these pages were created, many of them used hidden fields as in `System.Web.UI.WebControls.HiddenField`.  Now, it has been realized that the `Value` property of these hidden fields needs something like the following:

```
public override string Value
{
    get
    {
        return HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(base.Value);
    }
    set
    {
        base.Value = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(value);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to, in the `FormPage.cs` file, modify the get and set methods of `HiddenField` without creating a new class that inherits from it, so I won't have to replace every instance of `HiddenField` throughout all the pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an extension method to your HiddenField control--it doesn't require inheritance for it to work.  But the solution is also limited, since you'll have to change the code to reference the extension method by default.

```
public static void SetValue(this HiddenField c, string text)
{
    c.Value = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(text);
}

public static string GetValue(this HiddenField c)
{
    return HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(c.Value);
}
```

Comment: Well, it's an alternative.  Thanks.

Comment: I guess the reason I wanted to avoid inheriting is because I tried making a new class named `HiddenField` that extended the existing class of the same name.  I did this in another .cs file that was included in the `using` section at the top of each page.  That threw errors because of the ambiguity.  However, it looks like if I define the overriding class in `FormPage.cs`, it may work.

Comment: Actually, I think that's the best alternative--create a new class that extends the `HiddenField` class with your code. Just don't name it the same as the base class because of the problems with the ambiguity.  Then in your aspx pages do a global search for all instances of the `HiddenField` class and replace their declaration with an instance of your custom class.